# Mongoengine list filtering

Tags: python, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I have a list of required perms in some mongoengine's documents and I would like filtering on it.

Consider this Document:

```python
class Entry(Document):
    required_perms = ListField(StringField())

e = Entry(required_perms=['create', 'update'])
e.save()
```

Here are some usecases:

```python
all_perms = ['create', 'update', 'delete']

Entry.objects.filter(required_perms__in=all_perms)
[<Entry: Entry object>] # Returned because 'create' OR 'update' are in required_perms

Entry.objects.filter(required_perms__in=['create', 'delete'])
[<Entry: Entry object>] # Returned because 'create' is in required_perms

Entry.objects.filter(required_perms__all=all_perms)
[] # Not returned because 'delete' is not in required_perms
```

When querying with `$in`, I get the `Entry`, because at least one of the string is in the list. `$all` does not cover my needs because according to the doc it is the reverse of what I'm intending to do: *"every item in list of values provided is in array"* ; and I would like: *"every item in array is in list of provided values"*.

So, I would like to request something *like* this:

```python
Entry.objects.filter(everyoneof__required_perms__in=['create', 'delete'])
```

I tricked this to clearly explain it but this is ugly, not dynamic and *should* not be used:

```python
Entry.objects(Q(required_perms__0__in=all_perms) & Q(required_perms__1__in=all_perms))
"""
Can be tested with: all_perms = ['create', 'delete'] -> No results
     and: all_perms = ['create', 'update', 'delete'] -> 1 result
"""
```

Is there a way to do something like that ? Maybe with a raw query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the order then you can do a direct check eg:

```
Entry.objects.filter(required_perms=['create', 'delete'])
```

If the order isn't fixed or known then you can use the [`$all`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html?highlight=all#query-operators) operator:

```
Entry.objects.filter(required_perms__all=['create', 'delete'])
```

### Update

If you have to ensure that all elements in a list match the given requirements AND that they may or may not be present - that is not supported.  You'd have to do an `__in=` and then filter in your application.

I'm not sure of the approach.  Why worry about user having extra permissions?  Doesn't sound very flexible / future proof.

Comment: Thanks Ross, but this will work only if the given list is exactly the saved list.

Querying with this will not return any result for example :

`Entry.objects.filter(required_perms=['create', 'update', 'delete'])`

Comment: Have updated the answer with an example of the all operator - that should do as you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I've also updated with usecases and I hope a more concrete explanation. Thanks for spending time on this!

Comment: I see... In fact, I have a list of generic objects which should be accessible to users which have the required perms (per-object perms may vary). I thought storing the required perms was the best solution so that the filtering could be done on the database level. Thanks for all, I will inspect another approach.

Comment: In that case wouldn't $all be the best solution to ensure the user has all the required permissions to fetch the object?

Comment: No, or I don't see how, because `$all` checks that every value given (eg. `all_perms` in my example) is present in the field list. In my case `all_perms` is a list of a dozen of perms. Like I said previously, I would do an "inverted all" which is (currently) not available.